# sql query with email adresses in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little query, which is displaying a text if the server query_string exits in the database.
It works with all sorts of text an figures in mysql, instead of email adresses.
For example if the url looks like "example.com/query.php?test" it works.
If there is an email like "example.com/query.php?test@gmail.com" it doesn't work.
My DB table type is varchar(100).

Any idea?

```
    <?php

    $subscriber_email = ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    mysql_connect("server", "user", "pswd") or die (mysql_error ());

    mysql_select_db("newsletter") or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter submit` WHERE ID='test@gmail.com'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    echo mysql_error();

    echo (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) ? 'NO' : 'YES';

    ?>
```

Comment: What would happen if `$subscriber_email` contains: `5 OR 1=1`?

Comment: What happens when you execute your query from phpmyadmin ?

Comment: This was a good idea - with brackets it always results nothing, but if enter the email without brackets i get this error message:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 

Can you help me fixing this?

Comment: @fuez96 That's because you need to surround the email address with quotes as I keep repeating it, otherwise you get a syntax error. Furthermore, if you don't get any error message it probably means that there is no row corresponding to your query. Are you sure that there is a row whose ID field is test@gmail.com ?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure. The only Problem is - with quotes works nothing and without quotes normal values without an @ do.
I will try to insert the email adresses without an @ and remodify it later.

Comment: You need the quotes, there is something wrong either with your data or with your query. Can you post a few lines of the table ?

Answer (score 0):

You should [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) your inputs :

```
$subscriber_email = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Using a non escaped string causes an error that prevents your query to be executed.

Additionally, you should consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), mysql functions being deprecated.

**UPDATE** : I was a bit too fast and forgot to mention, you should put quotes on each side of your parameter :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter submit` WHERE ID='$subscriber_email'";
```

Comment: That does in no way answer his question.

Comment: @Daan, indeed, I was a bit to fast and forgot to add the part about the quotes, which IMO causes the error. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ vincenth, thx for your quick answer. I'm sorry but your code above doesn't work either. When I try the hook with the quotes also the normal querys without an @ won't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post the result of var_dump($sql); ?

Comment: Well that's weird, it should contain the query, I don't even understand how it can output "sql".

Comment: I'm sorry - i tried again and this is my output now:
string(61) "SELECT * FROM `newsletter submit` WHERE ID=test@gmail.com"

Comment: If your table's name contains space you should surround it by backticks, the email address should also be surrounded by quotes : SELECT * FROM `btu newsletter submit` WHERE ID="test@gmail.com"

Comment: I'm sorry but if email address is in quotes it does always output a false result. Even if i write manually "test@gmail.com" in code and not with the string.

Comment: You need to put backticks (alt gr + 7) surrounding your table name. I put them in my comment, but they were stripped off, that's why it's still not working

Comment: This query should work : SELECT * FROM \`btu newsletter submit\` WHERE ID="test@gmail.com"

Comment: The problem is, that the whole line needs to be in these quotes: " "
So I can only use these ' ' for the email, but this also won't work...

Comment: Try that then : SELECT * FROM \`btu newsletter submit\` WHERE ID='test@gmail.com' and if it's not working, use http://php.net/mysql_error and post the error message.

Comment: I use exactly this and tried to print mysql errors with: echo mysql_error();
I'm sorry but it doesn't display any errors. Is the error reporting code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_url()` like below

```
$url = 'example.com/query.php?test@gmail.com';
$parm = parse_url($url);
echo $parm['query'];
```